# Send POST data from NodeJs to PHP Symfony 5

Tags: php, node.js, symfony, http-post

I want to send POST data from NodeJS server (localhost:4000) to PHP symfony server (localhost:8000)

But every time when I'm trying to send it, I got always same result => empty array.

Here is my code:

**NodeJS**

```
        var data = {
            method: "disconnectFromGame",
        };
        var querystring = require("querystring");
        var qs = querystring.stringify(data);
        var qslength = qs.length;
        var options = {
            hostname: "http://localhost:8000",
            port: 80,
            path: "/game/api",
            method: 'POST',
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                'Content-Length': qslength
            }
        };
        var buffer = "";
        var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
            res.on('data', function (chunk) {
                buffer += chunk;
            });
            res.on('end', function () {
                console.log(buffer);
            });
        });

        req.write(qs);
        req.end();
```

It works fine, debugger stop me at the specific breakpoint, so communication is OK, but $request has always empty parameters..

**PHP Symfony 5**

```
public function engineApi(Request $request) {
    $user = $this->getUser();
    if(!$user) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute("app_login");
    }

    if (!$request->isXMLHttpRequest()) {
        return $this->redirectToRoute("app_homepage_show");
    }

    $entityManager = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $data = $request->request->all();
    $api = new Api($data, $user, $entityManager);
    return $api->processMethod();
}
```

[image: Debugger view for $request]

Comment: Not sure if it is related but in your hostname you have ":8000" and the port below is:80...

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Have you checked whether the data is put into the request, by inspecting your browser's network console?

Answer (score 0):

Your script works :

[image: Result: Html view of Symfony dump()]

How do you get the picture of your dump ? Because I think, this is where you made a mistake.
When you execute the NodeJs script, did you get a response from the Symfony server in your console ? Because if you put a dump() in your Symfony, you should have something like this (which is the raw view of html response with dump data from Symfony) :

[image: Result raw view of html Symfony dump view]

Comment: Its screen from PHPStorm with xdebug dialog. When i send the same request from ajax on the same server, i got parameters in $request->request->parameters.. but when i send it from nodejs server it will return empty array..

What do you thing about php blocks remote requests? But i dont know, because debugger stop me at the endpoint... so communication must be ok..

Comment: What is your result in the console when you run your NodeJs script ?

Comment: Can you describe how you do to trigger debugger with your NodeJS script ? I think you do somethnig wrong.

Comment: i just put breakpoint at php server in my endpoint.. it will stop me at this point but still $request parameters or $_POST are empty... and when i put exit() or dump i got same results like you but without parameters...

Comment: Ok. I ask you the question because when I run NodeJs, I got a response from the Symfony server with the dump but the debugger is not trigger. Did you have an answer from Symfony from the console where you run your NodeJs script ?